# Django-- form_valid() is not responding

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I've set the default post author to be null, and used the form_valid function to override the post author and assign to it the current logged in user.

the form_valid() function is taken from the official django docs but for some reason its doesnt do anything.

*my django versions are:
django-rest-framework = 3.12.2.
django = 3.1.4*

*models.py*

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField( 
        primary_key=True,
        default=uuid.uuid4,
        editable=False
    )
    author = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model() , on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True) # 
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
```

*serializers.py*

```
class RecipeCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('title', 'description')
```

*views.py*

```
class RecipeCreate(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeCreateSerializer

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        return super(RecipeCreate, self).form_valid(form)
```

hopefully someone out here will know how to fix this.
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing up Django's [class based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#models-and-request-user) and Django rest framework views. In the [docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself), it is stated that if you want to use `request.user` in your serializer, you must use the `perform_create` method. So first, you would have to add the `author` field to your `RecipeCreateSerializer` in `serializers.py`.

```
class RecipeCreateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe
        fields = ('title', 'description', 'author') # Add author now
```

and your `RecipeCreate` View would now have the `perform_create` method instead of `form_valid`:

```
class RecipeCreate(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    queryset = Recipe.objects.all()
    serializer_class = RecipeCreateSerializer

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```